# Count num_rows base on field value

Tags: php, mysql

*The actual problem is quite more complex than the post title :S

Suppose I have table

```
ID | vote_id |  vote_type |  vote_user

1  ----  2  -----   up -------    Tom
2  ----  3  -----   up -------    John
3  ----  3  -----   down -----    Harry
4  ----  4  -----   up -------    Tom
5  ----  2  -----   down -----    John
6  ----  3  -----   down -----    Tom
```

So what I want to do is

1. Query the table by specific **vote_id**
2. Then Count how many voted **up** and how many voted **down** from the query in 1
3. Then I want to check also that had **John** voted for that vote_id or not.

And the way I do is.

```
$up=0;
$down=0;
$voted="no"; 
$r=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM table_name WHERE vote_id == 3");

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r){
   if($row["vote_type"]=="up"){ $up++;}else{$down++;}
   if($row["vote_user"=="John"){ $voted="yes";}
 }
```

**But is there a way ( equivalent code ) to do this without using WHILE LOOP** because the actual table can be very large so running while loop can be very exhaustive :S

**EDIT**  Can I do with single query?

Comment: SQL has a lot of report-generating functionality.  One you might be interested in is GROUP BY

Comment: @GordonM : yeah i look into that but then I can't achive the 2nd and 3rd point together in a single query. Can I? Might require complex statement which I can't come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a single query

```
Select
  sum(case when vote_type = 'up' then 1 else 0 end) as up,
  sum(case when vote_type = 'down' then 1 else 0 end) as down,
  sum(case when vote_user = 'john' then 1 else 0 end) as john
from
  yourTable
where
  vote_id = 3
```

Or any variation of sum(case when)

Comment: OK Thanks so much, but one thing. Do you think this will perform better than two separate query? as DCoder commented in his/her answer that it possible but can perform worse... not sure if he/she mean this way or not .. Thanks

Comment: It won't be processing rows multiple times, and won't be making multiple connections, but will have a marginally higher CPU cost.  Depending on volume of rows, this is a common and perfectly acceptable pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Use two separate queries:

**Count all votes**:

    `SELECT vote_type, COUNT(*) AS amount
    FROM table_name
    WHERE vote_id = 3
    GROUP BY vote_type`

will return up to two rows:

```
vote_type | amount
----------+--------
up        | 1
down      | 2
```

**Find out if John voted**:

    `SELECT vote_type
    FROM table_name
    WHERE vote_id = 3
    AND vote_user = 'John'`

will return a row containing either `up`, `down` or `NULL` based on how John voted. Assuming he can only vote once...

Note that adding indexes on `vote_type` and maybe `vote_user` will help performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I just Edited the question as I want a SINGLE query. Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible, but the performance will be worse. Why do you have such a requirement?

Comment: Up to what I learned from reading different post, isn't it always better to minimize the query to database ( if its possible ). :)  But if you says that the performance will be worse then may be at the end I will end up with your solution :D.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can run this query to give you a table of votes up and down for a specific vote_id.

```
select vote_type, COUNT(*) from votes where vote_id = 2 AND group by vote_type
```

I would run another query to check to see if John voted for that vote_id or not

```
select count(*) from votes where vote_id = 2 AND vote_user = 'John'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I just Edited the question as I want a SINGLE query. Is it possible?

Comment: You can do it with a single query, but then you're back to the while loop :) You're probably better off with the different queries.

Comment: Umm ok. php/mysql people should make some function like  mysql_num_rows($r,$row["vote_id"]==3) ... hehe just an idea :P

Comment: You also want to minimize the amount of data being sent from your database to your app by reducing via queries. It's not always better to minimize the number of queries -- minimize query complexity and also the data sets that queries return.

Comment: OK so , "the amount of data return" also matter alot. I'll remember that. Thank You